# How to load typescript files from html in nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js

Trying to load a typescript file from html gives me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioqBH.png)
Code for the page

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="/static/main.tsx"></Script>

      <div className="sidebar">Hi</div>
      <div
        className="canvasContainer"
      >
        <canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

`main.tsx` Starts with `export {}` to make it run (else it would give me "cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules'..." error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The `script` tag should be in lowercase. i.e. `<script...` instead of `<Script...`</strike>

I think you should `import` your `main.tsx` instead of running `<Script src="/static/main.tsx"></Script>`. Unless I am mistaken — this is invalid or a very bad practice.

A more appropriate place to use `script` would be within the `<Head>...</Head>` section of a page, after importing `Next.js`' Head component via `import Head from "next/head"` if this is just for this page.

If this is for all your pages then do it on `_document.tsx`'s within `<Head>...</Head>`

Comment: Regarding your first line, OP is most likely using the [`next/script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script) component from Next.js, which is a wrapper around the HTML `<script>` element.

Comment: Oh thank you for clarifying this. I will edit my message to not mislead anyone

Comment: @juliomalves Yes I'm using ```next/script```, Everything used to work when it was javascript , But when I switched to typescript this happened.

Comment: replacing ```<Script src="/static/main.tsx"></Script>``` with ```<Script>{import('../static/main')}</Script>``` fixed the problem, Thank you for your help.